Where is the 6D-QSAR software Quasar(X) available?
Background: I'm working on a computational chemistry / drug discovery project and am interested in testing out different methods for doing QSAR/QSPR calculations on a set of published compounds I have found.
A few papers reference an interesting piece of software referred to as "Quasar" or "QuasarX" capable of building something called a quasi-atomistic binding-site surrogate model. Citations of this software primarily point to this publication.
Problem: This application seems very interesting, but I haven't been able to find any actual information on the availability of Quasar, though papers have been published using it as recently as 2024.
Goal: Can anyone provide information on Quasar's availability?
Thank you very much in advance!

Quasar$^X$  has been hosted by this domain: http://www.biograf.ch, which unfortunately seems to be down. Luckily, you can still use Wayback Machine to access a copy of the site.
You can download Quasar 5.2 either by accessing the site via Wayback Machine, or by using this link:
http://web.archive.org/web/20230328145629/https://www.biograf.ch/downloads/QuasarX_operatingsystem.zip
where you'll need to replace 'operatingsystem'  with either 'Macintosh', 'Windows' or 'Linux'.

Amazing! I can't thank you enough! I had never even though of using the Wayback Machine. Such a good idea!
